# Parallelizing a set intersection operation?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I have a file like this:

```
A 1
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 2
B 3
C 2
C 3
```

which I converted into the following data structure:

```
s = [set([1, 2, 3]), set([2, 3]), set([2,3])]
```

To find the length of the intersection of all 2-combinations, I am using the following:

```
from itertools import combinations
for i in combinations(s, 2):
    inter = i[0] & i[1]
    print len(inter)
```

The size of `s` is 300,000 distinct sets each having a length of about 1,000. There are two bottle-necks:

- Reading the file
- Computing the length of the intersection

The first one is unavoidable perhaps but the second one can be improved. I have a machine with 64 cores so I was wondering how to parallelize this program. Is there some kind of map reduce library available for a multi-core machine?

Comment: I came across this http://www.parallelpython.com/. It may be useful for you too.

Comment: Also, have you looked into multiprocessing module of python. http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Have you tried not printing each result with `print` as it is calculated, but instead collecting the data (use a list comprehension) and/or writing it to file (possibly via a generator), etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, check out the `multiprocessing` module. Also, while convenient, it isn't necessary to use `itertools.combinations()` to get a set of all unique 2-combinations. If you can accept the use of global variables, you could use `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` to farm it out to a pool of processes. For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def tally(n):
    return [len(s[n] & t) for t in s[n+1:]]

p=Pool()
for resultset in p.map(tally, xrange(len(s)), chunksize=1):
    for result in resultset:
        print result
```

`tally()` performs a set intersection on a set in `l` at position `n` with every other subsequent position in `l` in a single process. `p.map()` parallelizes that task for every position in `l` using as many processes as is returned in `cpu_count()`.

There's a full working example at https://gist.github.com/c576fd7f48be5f66deaa and for large data sets, I do get a significant improvement in performance on a quad-core machine compared to running just the built-in `map()` function on a single process.